# What is “more relevant content” in settings for Ask Different?

Tags: support

In the settings, there is a section we can enable or disable.

> **Use my on-site activity to show more relevant content (recommended)**
> If you opt-out, existing recommendations will be discarded within 24 hours.

There’s speculation it’s only for [stack overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371134/what-does-use-my-on-site-activity-to-show-more-relevant-content-mean-in-prefer), but I’m curious on this specific site how this setting is used and specifically where on a page it will show or not show.

What precisely is this relevant content and where is it displayed?

Comment: Sorry for only reading you linked to a question I already answered *after* writing my answer ...

Comment: I was on the process of editing as you answered. My bad

Answer (score 2):

It's a setting which can be configured on all sites, but in practice it only does something on Stack Overflow, where you have (unless you opt out) a personalized homepage showing only questions in tags where you are active.

It's not a widely documented feature, but it was mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349749/4751173) by then-staff member Nick Craver.

Comment: This would explain my mystery hunt not showing me any clues on any sites I frequent.

Comment: I am not sure (I wasn't around back then) but it could be that this is the final result of the [Recommended questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276840/4751173) project.